# spring cloud how to change prefix in the bootstrap.properties

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-cloud

Using spring-cloud

Currently I want to change the key name in bootstrap.properties
for example

```
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=false
```

to

```
xxx.consul.config.enabled=false
```

and the same function consul config will be disabled

any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you want to change this name? Because it is a reserved configuration and used in `ConsulConfigAutoConfiguration.java` in Spring Cloud Consul.

Comment: Integration spring cloud consul  to out self framework   we want same key prefix 
and   I  have solved this   thanks anyway